# Regular Expression with Lambda Expression

Tags: c#, regex, lambda

I've got several text files which should be tab delimited, but actually are delimited by an arbitrary number of spaces.  I want to parse the rows from the text file into a `DataTable` (the first row of the text file has headers for property names).  This got me thinking about building an extensible, easy way to parse text files.  Here's my current working solution:

```
string filePath = @"C:\path\lowbirthweight.txt";
            //regex to remove multiple spaces
            Regex regex = new Regex(@"[ ]{2,}", RegexOptions.Compiled);
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            var reader = ReadTextFile(filePath); 
            //headers in first row
            var headers = reader.First();
            //skip headers for data
            var data = reader.Skip(1).ToArray();
            //remove arbitrary spacing between column headers and table data
            headers = regex.Replace(headers, @" ");
            for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
            {
                data[i] = regex.Replace(data[i], @" ");
            }
            //make ready the DataTable, split resultant space-delimited string into array for column names
            foreach (string columnName in headers.Split(' '))
            {
                table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn() { ColumnName = columnName });
            }
            foreach (var record in data)
            {
                //split into array for row values
                table.Rows.Add(record.Split(' '));
            }
            //test prints correctly to the console
            Console.WriteLine(table.Rows[0][2]);
        }
        static IEnumerable<string> ReadTextFile(string fileName)
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(fileName))
            {
                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    yield return reader.ReadLine();
                }
            }
        }
```

In my project I've already received several large (gig +) text files that are not in the format in which they are purported to be.  So can I see having to write methods such as these with some regularity, albeit with a different regular expression.  Is there a way to do something like 
`data =data.SmartRegex(x => x.AllowOneSpace)` where I can use a regular expression to iterate over the collection of strings?

Is something like the following on the right track?

```
public static class SmartRegex
    {
        public static Expression AllowOneSpace(this List<string> data)
        {
            //no idea how to return an expression from a method
        }
    }
```

I'm not too overly concerned with performance, just would like to see how something like this works

Comment: This code doesn't look extensible *or* easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consult with your data source and find out why your data is bad.

As for the API design that you are trying to implement:

```
public class RegexCollection
{
    private readonly Regex _allowOneSpace = new Regex(" ");

    public Regex AllowOneSpace { get { return _allowOneSpace; } }
}

public static class RegexExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<string[]> SmartRegex(
        this IEnumerable<string> collection,
        Func<RegexCollection, Regex> selector
    )
    {
        var regexCollection = new RegexCollection();
        var regex = selector(regexCollection);
        return collection.Select(l => regex.Split(l));
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var items = new List<string> { "Hello world", "Goodbye world" };

var results = items.SmartRegex(x => x.AllowOneSpace);
```

Comment: I know why the data source is bad, unfortunately that's not something that can be fixed on SO :)

Comment: could you explain this code? I don't understand the last two lines of code.

Comment: Which last two lines?

Comment: Do you know what LINQ `Select` does?

Comment: yes, but I've not seen often enough to full understand LINQ syntax that is not `x => x.SomeMethod`.  I'm not well-versed with creating my own delegates.

Comment: I edited it to make it more clearer. `Select` will iterate over each element in collection and split the element using the `regex`.

Comment: Ah, this makes more sense to me now.  It's easier for me to see that your delegate's taking a collection of regex properties and returning one of them.  Great job.

Comment: I really would convert the select contents to a method group, since `Split` already takes and returns the correct types. It may look odd at first, but if the contract is met, I'm inclined to take advantage of that.

Comment: I would do this as well, but I didn't want it to be more confusing. That is simply a matter of style.